# Recursive functions & family trees

Tags: function, python-3.x, dictionary, recursion

I am stuck with a recursive functions for a given family tree in a dictionary format (keys are parents, values are children).

Per example `family_tree = {"Adam": ["Michael", "Clara", "Daniel"], "Clara": [], "Daniel": ["Elizabeth", "Hans"], etc.}`

Adam in this example has 3 children, one of which is Clara. She has no children, etc., etc. Pretty straightforward.

Now, for the recursive functions.

1. Write a function depth(person) that returns the depth of the person's family tree.

If a person has no children, the depth of her family tree is 1. If (s)he has children, but no grandchildren, the depth is 2. If (s)he has grandchildren but no grandgrandchildren, the depths is 3. And so forth.

Shouldn't this be working?

`def children(person):
    return family_tree[person]`

`def depth(person):
    if not children(person):
        return 1
    for child in children(person):
        a = depth(child)
        if a!= None:
            return a + 1`

Thank you! :)

Comment: Could you demonstrate any effort at solving this, to give an idea where you need help?

Comment: Oh, I need help with recursion in general. I have no idea how to approach this.

Comment: Did the 2nd one! Updated the question. :)

Comment: Please edit the posted code so it is readable (line breaks and indenting matter)

Comment: Depth is not dependent on the number of children, as your code suggests.

Comment: Updated. Is this better? I'm still not getting the right result.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your code and accurately describe the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logic for computing depth is:

```
if a person has no children
    depth is 1
else
    depth is 1 + (maximum depth of person's children)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is the innermost condition:

- You should *always* return an integer result; **None** is not a good choice.
- You need to return 1 plus the *maximum* depth of all children.  Your current code returns the depth of the *first* child plus 1.

Be patient in your inner loop.  If there are children, just keep track of the largest depth you've found so far.  When you finish the loop, *then* add 1 and return that.